# Struggling with calling overloaded methods from interface to class

Tags: java, class, methods, interface

So i have interface with these methods

```
public interface Figura {
    public double poleFigury();
    Object nowyObiekt();
    public double obwódFigury();
}
```

and i didin't put parameters so i could call the same method 2 times, but something isn't just right, and couldn't figure out what could it be

```
public class Prostokąt implements Figura {
    double a;
    double b;

    public Prostokąt(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }


    @Override
    public double poleFigury(double a, double b) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nowyObiekt() {
        Prostokąt nowyProstokąt = new Prostokąt(7.8,8.2);
        return nowyProstokąt;
    }

    @Override
    public double obwódFigury() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

that's the second part of a code

Comment: Which part doesn’t work, also need to see main part with using the class..

Comment: no, no, there is no main class, i was only told to do the inteface and 3 classes that inherit method after it. When I try to put some parameters into brackets it says that i should make a abstract class or implement the same method without parameters:(

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. The errors you have made are fundamental and demonstrate no understanding of what you are doing. This forum isn't really designed around helping students and 'newbies'; you'll find it harsh and somewhat unhelpful at your level. I'd strongly recommend going to find an online course or tutorial and following that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes that inherit Interfaces should implement or override all the methods of the Interface, that's why it has a @Override. But if an Abstract or another Interface inherits an Interface, you can inherit the methods without implementing or overriding.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined in the interface this method with no arguments

```
public double poleFigury();
```

but you implement it with arguments

```
 @Override
public double poleFigury(double a, double b) {
    return 0;
}
```

you have to define this method in its interface

```
public double poleFigury(double a, double b);
```

then you have

```
public interface Figura {
    public double poleFigury();
    public double poleFigury(double a, double b);
    Object nowyObiekt();
    public double obwódFigury();
}

public class Prostokąt implements Figura {
    double a;
    double b;

    public Prostokąt(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

     @Override
    public double poleFigury() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double poleFigury(double a, double b) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nowyObiekt() {
        Prostokąt nowyProstokąt = new Prostokąt(7.8,8.2);
        return nowyProstokąt;
    }

    @Override
    public double obwódFigury() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly i did that, but the thing is that i need overloads of this method, I need public double poleFigury(double a, double b); as well as the same method but with only 1 argument

Comment: @Yashiru99 you have to define that method in the interface. i have updated my answer